# Cloud functions and local dependecies

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy to google cloud using deploy command and my code refers local package using the github url. I getting below when deploying using gcloud deploy command. So in this example. My endpoints package refers to local package price using the full git url. What am I missing here?

```
package endpoints

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/piscean/pricing/price"
    "net/http"
)

func LawnPricing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    m, err := price.Pricing()

    c, err := json.Marshal(m)

    w.Write(c)
    r.Body.Close()
}
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/endpoints/pricing.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/piscean/pricing/price" in any of:
>           /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/github.com/piscean/pricing/price (vendor tree)
>           /go/src/github.com/piscean/pricing/price (from $GOROOT)
>           /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/github.com/piscean/pricing/price (from $GOPATH)
>   /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/endpoints/zipcode.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/piscean/pricing/zip" in any of:
>           /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/github.com/piscean/pricing/zip (vendor tree)
>           /go/src/github.com/piscean/pricing/zip (from $GOROOT)
>           /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/github.com/piscean/pricing/zip (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Vendor (put into `vendor` folder) your dependencies. Tolls like `dep` and modules support that.

Comment: As someone already answered, you need a dependency management tool like `deb` which will setup these dependencies for you.

Comment: I am using VGO with GOMODULES111=ON. It does create Vendor folder. I see all dependencies in vendor folder but not for internal packages.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the dependency package management tool for this called as **dep**.

Install dep by using the command:

`go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep`

This would create the binary of dep in the **GOBIN** directory. Navigate to directory where main package is present and execute the command:

For Windows:
`%GOBIN%\dep.exe init`

For Linux:
`$GOBIN\dep init`

This would create **Gopkg.toml** and **Gopkg.lock** files along with the **vendor** folder that would solve your issue.

**Reference**: https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

The cloud function is a managed environment which google provision for us during the deployment of the function. While setting the environment google supplies all the system dependencies but any external dependency should be handled by function itself.

While resolving external dependencies, it looks for Vendor directory , GOROOT and GOPATH to find to package being imported. If package is not found at any of these locations , you get this error.

Solution

- Supply your package as vendor dependency by manually copying it there.
- OR create a go module for your package and supply go.mod file while deploying the cloud function. This way go knows where to find the package before building the function.

Reference - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/issues/1600